# JavaScript, combine matching elements in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var binary = [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0];
```

I have a function which produces a random array of bits. I would like to combine matching elements and return an array stating how many elements were repeated. The above giving the output = [1,2,3,2,1,1].

Are there any features in JavaScript which would allow me to do this? I have tried searching but not really sure how to describe what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Iterate and count? I mean, it's basic RLE w/o referencing what you're encoding, right?

Comment: as a side note both arrays can easily be generated in the same loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `reduce()` method and store last element in one variable.

```js
var binary = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0];
let last = null;

var result = binary.reduce((r, e) => {
  if (last == null || last != e) r.push(1);
  else r[r.length - 1]++;
  last = e;
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```js
var binary = [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0];

var result = []; // result array
var value = binary[0]; // initial value
var counter = 1; // counter of the values
// Start the loop with 2nd value
for (var i = 1; i < binary.length; i++) {
  // if the value in array is same as stored value, increment counter
  if(value === binary[i]) {
    counter++;
  } else {
  /* if the value is different, push the counter in result 
  ** and reset value and counter */
    result.push(counter);
    value = binary[i];
    counter = 1;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check the last element while reducing the array and either push the increased last value or take `1` for concatination.

```js
var binary = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    result = binary.reduce((r, v, i, a) => r.concat((a[i - 1] === v && r.pop()) + 1), []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the way that i founded to check that binary in array is continuously repeated or not

```
    var output = [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0];
    var result = []
    var counter = 1;
    for(i=0;i<output.length;i++){
        if(output[i] === output[i+1])
            counter++;
        else{
            result.push(counter);
            counter=1;
            }
     }
     console.log(result)
```

here is an output [ 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1 ]
and this code is simple to understand

Comment: Please provide description to your solution. A post with only code is not complete

Comment: first it match first character of array with second  if it is matched then counter will increase with 1 (in our case it is not matched ) if not matched push counter in to result which is empty in initially and assign counter with 1 (why counter is 1 ?because if there not matched then at least one character is there   )

Comment: @alamoot Sometimes I'd agree; in this case, since it's clearly already a homework assignment, adding an explanation makes answering even *worse*, because it removes even *more* of the onus on the OP to actually *learn*.

Comment: @Dave, its a personal project, not a homework assignment. Clearly.

Comment: @Future I see. Personally I would have spent more time with it before giving up, and included your best effort(s) in the question as well, but that's just me. And it's a very odd "personal project", but I have odder ones, so who am I to judge.

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter and slower alternative:

```js
console.log( [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0].join('').match(/0+|1+/g).map(m => m.length) )
```